# When I try to update cells in h:dataTable, it will not do it

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, facelets

I have an h:dataTable with data generated from an ArrayList with custom object Result.
When I try to enable editing of cells, it will not allow me to do so. I suspect that it request data from the server and overrides my last choice.

My `<h:dataTable>` form and the complete xhtml document

```
<!-- language: xhtml -->
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>IGNORED</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="../templates/masterLayout.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="windowTitle"> #{msgs.viewResultsTitle}</ui:define>
            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form>
                    <h:dataTable value="#{managedBean.viewResultList}" var="res"
                                 styleClass="tracks"
                                 headerClass="trackHeader"
                                 columnClasses="oddColumn,evenColumn">
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.trackID}</f:facet>
                                #{res.track_name}
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.startnumber}</f:facet>
                                <h:inputText value="#{res.startnumber}" size="5" rendered="#{res.editable}" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{res.startnumber}" rendered="#{not res.editable}" />
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.time}</f:facet>
                                <h:inputText value="#{res.time}" size="10" rendered="#{res.editable}" >
                                    <f:validator validatorId="ResultValidator" />
                                    <f:converter converterId="ResultConverter" />                                    
                                </h:inputText>
                                <h:outputText value="#{res.time}" rendered="#{not res.editable}" />
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.runnerID}</f:facet>
                                #{res.runner_name}
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.divID}</f:facet>
                                #{res.division_value}
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <h:commandLink value="#{msgs.edit}" action="#{managedBean.editAction(res)}" rendered="#{not res.editable}"/>
                       </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                                <h:commandLink value="#{msgs.saveChanges}" action="#{managedBean.saveAction(res)}" />
                       </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
            </h:form>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

It calls the managedBean.editAction wich looks like this:

```
public String editAction(Result result) {
result.setEditable(true);
return null;
}
```

It bassicly set all the result objects to editable. But when I press the  it loads the page and nothing happends.

I've followed the tut at [www.mkyoung.com jsf tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-update-row-in-jsf-datatable/)

Comment: It seems like `result` is one entry in the table. Which one does it refer to?

Comment: It refers to an res object from dataTable. Don't know why I had not passed it along with managedBean.editAction(res), it do now. But it still don't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what your `managedBean` looks like, here are some hints:

- `viewResultList()` should not update the result list but only return it. Otherwise changes to entries in that list might be overwritten if you don't update your model first (e.g. write them to the database if you load the results from there).
- `result.setEditable(true);` seems to refer to *one* object in your list, or it might even refer to an object *not* in that list. Note that only that object is set to editable. 

  If you want make all entries editable, you either have to set a global property in your managed bean and check that in your table or iterate over the result list and call `setEditable(true)` on *each* entry in that list.

  Note that in the example you followed, the `editAction()` actually takes an object parameter `order` which defines which entry in `orderList` will be set to editable.

Comment: viewResultList() only returns an object of ArrayList<Result>, so this does not update the table, only represents the data. Or?
the editAction() is missing a result parameter which I have now updatet. But this still don't work..

Comment: @zo0mbie Just some additional (and trivial) questions: Did you check that `editAction(res)` is called? Did you wrap the `<h:dataTable>` with a `<h:form>`? You didn't tell us but I assume you're using JSF 2 and a compatible container, don't you? I know these questions are trivial but I'd rather like to eliminate the most obvious things that might be assumed and thus be overlooked.

Comment: editAction(res) is called and I can access res here. <h:dataTable> is wrapped inside a <h:form>. I'm using JSF2. I'm unsure about what you mean with container?

Comment: @zo0mbie with `compatible container` I mean an application server that is capable of dealing with JSF 2 applications. Unless I overlooked something your code should work, but it's hard to tell without seeing the whole XHTML and the complete managed bean. Did you check whether there are any conversion or validation errors? In that case the model would not be updated and if you don't render messages on your page they might only be visible in your server logs.

Comment: I've added the entire XHTML document to my main question. There are no validation errors or conversion. My methods `saveAction(res)` and `editAction(res)` is accessed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the help.

I figured out the problem. It was with from where the data was populated from -> a database. 
And `editAction(res)` saved the state to a local arraylist.
So when I updated the `editable` it were not saved to the database.

Comment: So the data was reloaded from the db when the view was refreshed?